# Как установить родителя у объекта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как программно удочерить обьект или убрать родителя у обьекта в юнити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Настолько банальный вопрос можно было найти в документации ;)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

Пример:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public void Example(Transform newParent) {
        // установить родителя, изменить ориентацию дочернего объекта в пространстве
        // относительно родителя
        this.transform.SetParent(newParent);

        // установить родителя, не изменять ориентацию дочернего объекта в пространстве
        this.transform.SetParent(newParent, false);

        // убрать родителя
        this.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
}
```

Также есть более короткий способ:

```
transform.parent = newParent;
transform.parent = null;
```